# 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeThis through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, methods

This is where the object is created, a new instance is created when the space key is pressed:

```
/* SHOOTING */
function fireRocket():void
{
    if (fireHold == 0)
    {
        fireHold = 1;
        var Timer = setInterval(fireDelay,fireRate);

    function fireDelay()
        {
            fireHold = 0;
            clearInterval(Timer);
        }
        if (rocketContainer.numChildren < 7)
        {
            trace(rocketContainer.numChildren)
            var rocketGameObject = new rocketObject  ;
            rocketContainer.addChild(rocketGameObject);
            rocketGameObject.x = spaceShip.x + 35;
            rocketGameObject.y = spaceShip.y + 35;
        }
        else
        {
            trace("Too many rockets present");
        }
    }
}
```

Once a hit is confirmed (via the hit test below), the following should run:

```
function hitTest(evt:Event):void
{
    /* HIT TEST */
    for (var i=0; i < rocketContainer.numChildren; i++)
    {
        for (var j=0; j < enemyContainer.numChildren; j++)
        {
            if (rocketContainer.getChildAt(i).hitTestObject(enemyContainer.getChildAt(j)))
            {
                trace(rocketContainer.getChildAt(i));
                rocketContainer.getChildAt(i).removeThis();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that is meant to handle movement and removal of the object when called using a method:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public class rocketClass extends MovieClip
    {

        public function rocketClass()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,rocketMove);
        }
        function rocketMove(evt:Event):void
        {
            this.x +=  20;
            if (this.x > stage.stageWidth)
            {
                removeThis();
            }
        }
        public function removeThis():void
        {
            trace("reached")
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rocketMove);
        }

    }

}
```

Now when I do `trace(rocketContainer.getChildAt(i));` in the hit confirmed, it returns `[object rocketObject]`. So I can only assume it is successfully detecting the fact that it is an object, this being the object that I want to remove.

BUT, when I want to remove it using a method of a class like this `rocketContainer.getChildAt(i).removeThis();` I get the following error:

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeThis through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject

Comment: getChildAt(int n) return an Object of the type DisplayObject, not rocketClass. before calling the function, create a temporary variable of the rocketclass type and cas the getchildat() to the rocketclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast rocketContainer.getChildAt(i) to your class rocketObject, because getChildAt() return DisplayObject. It will be looks like:

```
(rocketContainer.getChildAt(i) as rocketClass).removeThis();
```

or

```
rocketClass(rocketContainer.getChildAt(i)).removeThis();
```

---

P.S. In AS3 preferable that class name was started from symbol in uppercase. rocketClass -> RocketClass.

P.P.S. And part "class" in class name is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate what I said in my comment and what Crabar wrote in his answer, you need to cast to the appropriate Class when you are using getChildAt(int).

Crabars answer should work, and here is an alternative way (not that much different.) for better readability.

```
var temp:rocketClass = rocketContainer.getChildAt(i) as rocketClass;
temp.removeThis();
```

One point of confusion might be: why does hitTestObject() work? The answer to this: because hitTestObject() is a method of the DisplayObject class.